# Microsoft Mixed Reality Feature Tool will not open - Computer information, Specs, and Program Logs for reference

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am a student learning to use Unity for HoloLens 2 Development. I am working through the guide in link 1. I am trying to get the Mixed Reality Feature Tool working, but it will not open. The process appears in task manager and draws memory, but it will not open as a window.

My system summary is:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz   1.60 GHz
Installed RAM   6.00 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

I have windows 10 Pro and my OS build is 19043.1706

The program logs says:

"Mixed Reality Feature Tool 1.0.2206.1
[6/11/2022 4:26:48 PM] Refreshing the Primary catalog.
[6/11/2022 4:26:48 PM] Reading Primary feed
[6/11/2022 4:26:50 PM] Reading version information for com.microsoft.altspacevr_uploader
[6/11/2022 4:26:50 PM] Reading additional information for com.microsoft.altspacevr_uploader"

Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: I cannot see the hyperlink you attached. Do you download the tool from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102778 ? While .Net 5.0 Runtime is also required for this app. Please find the installer on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: Okay, I moved computer and it works so, meh. IDK what was wrong.

Comment: When I double-click on `MixedRealityFeatureTool.exe` file to launch the `Mixed Reality Feature Tool`, I get `To run this application, you must install .NET` but I already have `.NET 6.0.300` installed. I understand from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/welcome-to-mr-feature-tool) that I need `.NET 5.0 runtime` but when I go to the download page, it explicitly says `This release has reached end of life, meaning it is no longer supported. We recommend moving to a supported release, such as 6.0 Runtime`. Do I really need .NET5 then?

Comment: Yeah, it has to be 5.0